# Using webpack: Is it standard practice/ recommended to expose entire `node_modules` as static content?

Tags: node.js, express, bower, webpack

Reading up on webpack and there does not seem anything out there which tells you what is recommended way of bundling and exposing static content taking into consideration that you probably have a mix of third party packages installed using bower and some packages using npm.

Question is

Should i skip bower entirely and expose npm modules as static content?

OR

Use bower and npm modules and expose both as static content.

Comment: What do you mean for "exposing static content"? Expose the path to the public so they could use `<script src="path/to/your/bower_components/jquery">`?

Comment: Meant publicly accessible content which mostly comprises of static assets, ie js, css, images

Comment: In webpack/browserify, you should just `require` them and they'll exist in your `bundle.js` file. All you need is to expose the compiled single `bundle.js` file. :)

Comment: @TomChen - You are correct. If you post the comment as an answer, i will accept it.